# Fazer modal aparecer na tela após criá

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('a[rel=modal]').click( function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('href');
  var a1 = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
    a1[i] = (id[i+1]);
  }
  var a2 = a1.join('');
  var idTime = parseInt(a2);


  modaisTime= $('#modaisTime');
  var t = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Times'));
  modaisTime.html('');
  modaisTime.append('<div id="'+ idTime +'" class="modal modal-fixed-footer"><div class="modal-content"><h4 class="center-align">Time</h4><li class="divider1"></li><p class="flow-text col s12 m6">Nome: '+t[idTime].nome+'</p><p class="flow-text col s12 m6">CNPJ: '+t[idTime].c+'</p><p class="flow-text col s12 m6">Responsável: '+t[idTime].nomeR+'</p><p class="flow-text col s12 m6">CPF: '+t[idTime].cpfR+'</p></div><div class="modal-footer"><button id="editar" class="modal-action waves-effect waves-red btn-flat" type="button" onclick="editar('+idTime+')">Editar</button></div></div></div>');
  $(id).toggle();   
});
```

```html
<div id="mostrarTimes">
  <h5 class="col s7">Flamengo</h5>
  <a href="#0" rel="modal"></a>
 </div>
 
 <div id="modaisTime">
```

É o seguinte, eu queria fazer isso já mostrando o modal com o href, mas eu não consigo, aguem saberia como fazer pra apos o modal ser criado ele abrir?

Comment: Qual é o Modal que estás a usar? Bootstrap?

Comment: @LocalHost, [esse tipo de melhorias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/199894/revisions) podem esconder o problema da pergunta, por isso é melhor não fazer. Se o problema for a falta desse `>` vai ser dificil alguém descobrir uma vez que a pergunta não o reflete mais.

Comment: @Sergio, ah sim, Compreendi. Devo desfazer então? É que achei que ele esqueceu na hora da digitação, assim como o resto da div, que parece estar faltando...

Comment: @LocalHost deixamos até o AP aparecer por aqui e explicar melhor a pergunta. A intenção é boa claro! :)

Comment: Teste isso, usando bootstrap:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp